# random forest: error in dealing with factor levels in R

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction, r-factor

I am using `rf` model in `R` to predict a binary outcome 0 or 1. I have categorical variables (coded as numbers) in my input data which are coded as factor while training. I use `factor()` function in `R` to convert the variable as factor. So for every categorical variable`x`,my code is like this.

```
feature_x1=factor(feature_x1) # Convert the variable into factor in training data. 
#This variable takes 3 levels 0,1,2
```

This works perfectly fine while training the model. Let us assume my model object is `rf_model`. While running the model on new data which is just a vector of numbers. I first convert the number into factors for feature_x1

```
newdata=data.frame(1,2)
colnames(newdata)=c("feature_x1","feature_x2")
newdata$feature_x1=factor(newdata$feature_x1)
score=pred(rf_model,newdata,type="prob")
```

I am receiving the following error

> Error in predict.randomForest(rf_model, newdata,type = "prob") : 
>     New factor levels not present in the training data

How to deal with this error, because in reality, after training the model we will always have to deal with data for which outcome is unknown which is a just a single record.

Please let me know if more clarity or code is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
newdata$feature_x1 <- factor(newdata$feature_x1, levels=levels(feature_x1))
```

Comment: It's always more friendly to say what you had tried in the question, especially if your example is not self-contained.  I am sure more answers will pop up when you make your example runnable.

Comment: Thanks it is working now. The reason it was not working previously was because I was using  as.data.frame() in my code instead of data.frame()